# Post-Production Model Monitoring?

Tags: r, generalized-linear-model

I am interested in model monitoring techniques. To be clear, for production of a statistical model, let's say GLM, with a set of covariates (continuous). The model will go into production (live scoring of data) soon.

I have used PSI in the past, with some success. It is at a high level. I have been thinking about using something more granular, perhaps control charts for the predictors. Is that the right approach?